# Find which points belong to a cluster in DBSCAN in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

Hi Guys I have fitted a DBSCAN model on a set of points (4953 points). Now I need to find the points which belong to different clusters i.e which all input values belong to which all clusters.I have total of 10 clusters.How can I find this out?

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.0003,min_samples=20,n_jobs=-1).fit(X_scaled)
y_pred = db.fit_predict(X_scaled)
pred_labels = db.labels_
print(len(pred_labels))
n_clusters_ = len(set(pred_labels))- (1 if -1 in pred_labels else 0)
print(n_clusters_)
plt.scatter(list(range(len(df_median2))),X_scaled[:,0],c=y_pred, cmap='Paired')
plt.ylim(0.1,0.4)
```

The above is the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have your `X_scaled` array of input values (and possibly, the `X` array of original values before scaling) and the `pred_labels` array of cluster labels.  The value of `n_clusters_` will be one higher than the value of `len(set(pred_labels))` if some samples were not assigned to a cluster and were categorized as noise.  But the two arays have the same number of elements in the same order, so you can look up values in `pred_labels` array for each element in the `X_scaled` array, e.g., `pred_labels[0]` will return the cluster label for the first sample.  If you see `-1` among any labels, those are not cluster labels, but just a way of denoting noise samples not assigned to any cluster.

You can also concatenate the two arrays so the cluster labels are saved side-by-side with the original samples:

```
import numpy as np
samples_w_lbls = np.concatenate((X_scaled,pred_labels[:,np.newaxis]),axis=1)
```

Then, you can filter that combined array to rows having a particular cluster label value:

```
#Get rows with cluster label value of 5:
filter = np.asarray([5])
samples_w_lbls[np.in1d(samples_w_lbls[:,-1], filter)]
```